# Is Azure Search as a service going to be deprecated

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

While evaluating Azure Search for possible implementation I discovered that the MSDN forum specific to Azure Search was only recently closed down. They advise that questions regarding Search be instead asked here on Stack Overflow.

This strikes me as a bit unusual, so my question is this: Is the fact that Azure Search is no longer a first-class citizen on MSDN indicative of a potential deprecation of this service from Azure?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all :) You may want to use "Azure Cognitive Search" in your searches however, as this is the branding going forward. The team also generally prefers to standardize on answering questions on SO.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I did note the service name change and should have included the full name in my question. When attempting to ask a question on MSDN, i was told that the forum for the service was locked, which i thought was odd since all the other services all still have dedicated forums there; So wanted to make sure that the closing of the forum for this service was indicative of a larger issue with the service?

Comment: It is not, you can be sure of it.